# How to sort a list of restaurant names by restaurant rating (possibly from Google Places or Yelp Fusion API)

Tags: csv, sorting, google-places-api, yelp-fusion-api

I have a csv file with thousands of restaurant names and addresses that I need to sort by rating (data that is not in the csv). Is there a way to fill in the csv with this data? Possibly with Google Places API or Yelp Fusion API?

Comment: Please, show us what you already done, so we could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Both the Google Places API and Yelp Fusion API let you obtain a restaurant’s rating if you query with the business name and address. I’m going to explain how to do this but, first a caution about compliance. What you describe is clearly against the terms of service for both APIs. The only permitted use of their data is to display it on a publicly available website or app. Fetching and retaining it in a csv file is clearly improper. The APIs are intended for real-time query and immediate display of results for your users.

Google requires that the Places data be displayed in conjunction with a Google map or an approved "powered by Google" image. Additionally, no "pre-fetching, caching, or storage of content" is permitted. For details see https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/policies

Yelp requires attribution, basically requiring you to display the star rating and the Yelp logo with a link back to the business page on Yelp for the restaurant you have queried. See https://www.yelp.com/developers/display_requirements Furthermore, you can’t “cache, record, pre-fetch, or otherwise store any portion of the Yelp Content for a period longer than twenty-four (24) hours from receipt of the Yelp Content, or attempt or provide a means to execute any scraping or "bulk download" operations.” For full text and terms see https://www.yelp.com/developers/api_terms

With the legalese out of the way, here’s how to request a restaurant’s rating from Google Places:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=Applebees,234 W 42nd St,New York,NY&inputtype=textquery&fields=formatted_address,name,rating&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

And, the JSON response:

```
{
    "candidates": [
        {
            "formatted_address": "234 W 42nd St, New York, NY 10036, USA",
            "name": "Applebee's Grill + Bar",
            "rating": 3.6
        }
    ],
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Here is the same request for Yelp Fusion. There is no way to request just the rating. Results always contain everything in their database for the restaurant:

```
https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=applebees&location=234 W 42nd St,New York,NY&limit=1
```

JSON response:

```
{
    "businesses": [
        {
            "id": "gytFjzBw-z5LZD-6JSMChg",
            "alias": "applebees-grill-bar-new-york-3",
            "name": "Applebee's Grill + Bar",
            "image_url": "https://s3-media1.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/CLizyj9S7pMvwGNm2dgdiQ/o.jpg",
            "is_closed": false,
            "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/applebees-grill-bar-new-york-3?adjust_creative=pnOv3Zj2REsNDMU4Z3-SLg&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=pnOv3Zj2REsNDMU4Z3-SLg",
            "review_count": 444,
            "categories": [
                {
                    "alias": "tradamerican",
                    "title": "American (Traditional)"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "burgers",
                    "title": "Burgers"
                },
                {
                    "alias": "sportsbars",
                    "title": "Sports Bars"
                }
            ],
            "rating": 2,
            "coordinates": {
                "latitude": 40.756442,
                "longitude": -73.988838
            },
            "transactions": [
                "delivery",
                "pickup"
            ],
            "price": "$$",
            "location": {
                "address1": "234 W 42nd St",
                "address2": "",
                "address3": "",
                "city": "New York",
                "zip_code": "10036",
                "country": "US",
                "state": "NY",
                "display_address": [
                    "234 W 42nd St",
                    "New York, NY 10036"
                ]
            },
            "phone": "+12123917414",
            "display_phone": "(212) 391-7414",
            "distance": 5.938732504864397
        }
    ],
    "total": 2900,
    "region": {
        "center": {
            "longitude": -73.98880004882812,
            "latitude": 40.75648701137637
        }
    }
}
```